# Split String Into Components

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I am try to split the following string in to 3 parts:

```
Esmael20170101one => Esmael 20170101 one
```

What are the options?

Comment: You should provide more details.

Comment: What is condition on which you want to split? When letter meets number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest *matching* instead of *splitting*:

```
  string source = "Esmael20170101one";

  var match = Regex.Match(source, 
    @"^(?<name>[A-Za-z]+)(?<code>[0-9]+)(?<suffix>[A-Za-z]{3})$");

  string name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
  string code = match.Groups["code"].Value;
  string suffix = match.Groups["suffix"].Value;
```

if you insist on `Regex.Split`:

```
  string[] items = Regex.Split(source, "([0-9]+)");

  string name = items[0];
  string code = items[1];
  string suffix = items[2];
```

Comment: Both of these can fail on an edge case where the name (at the end) or the *suffix* (at the beginning) happens to have a number in it

Comment: @OmegaMan: quite right, that's why *more details* should be provided (please, see comments to the question). If your hypothesis (that `20170101` is in fact `1 Jan 2017`) is correct one, then your solution is a better one; +1 for the observation

Comment: You have both examples though. +1

Comment: The answer Dmitry is suggesting was ok for this case.Here is specification in detail: The first part is always string, the middle part is nummeric with any length and the last part could be any string with length of 3 characters.

Comment: @Esmael: Next time, please, start with the specification ;)

Comment: Sorry. but the last part is a string that also could be a 3 digit number. Is it ok to write: @"^(?<name>[A-Za-z]+)(?<code>[0-9]+)(?<suffix>[A-Z0-9]{3}+)$");

Comment: @Esmael: It should be `@"^(?<name>[A-Za-z]+)(?<code>[0-9]+)(?<suffix>[A-Z0-9]{3})$‌​"`: just `{3}`, not `{3}+`; if you want *three or more* then the right syntax is `{3,}`, finally `{,3}` means *three or less*

Comment: It shall be exactly 3 chracters or digits. Thanks for your detailed description.

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression to use is `([a-zA-Z]*)(\d+)([a-zA-Z]*)`

```
string input = "Esmael20170101one";
var match = new Regex("([a-zA-Z]*)(\\d+)([a-zA-Z]*)").Match(input);
if (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[3].ToString());
}
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use regex, you can define what areas to capture. For example it appears that the middle component is a date, so why not specify what the date pattern is such as

```
^                # Beginning of String
(?<Name>[^\d]+)  # Capture to `Name`
(?<Date>\d{8})   # Capture to `Date`
(?<Note>.+)      # Capture to `Note`
$                # End of string
```

Because I have commented this you will need to use the pattern only option of `IgnorePatternWhitespace` which just tells the parser to strip the comments (`#`) out.

The result will be this in a single match

[image]

- `Group[0]` has the whole thing matched.
- `Group["Name"]` or `Group[1]` is the name that is found.
- `Group["Date"]` or `Group[2]` is the date that is found.
- `Group["Note"]` or `Group[3]` is the note which is found.

---

As Dmitry pointed out, we need more information. All of these patterns can fail if there are numbers found in either of the groups depending on their location. If you know that all dates are within the 21st century adjust my pattern to be `(?<Date>20\d{6})` to make sure that a true date is captured in that field; though it is not foolproof.

Comment: Here is specification in detail: The first part is always string, the middle part is nummeric with any length and the last part could be any string with length of 3 characters.

Comment: @Esmael why didn't you put that in originally?